# Installing Jupyter on Anaconda using conda install

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I have tried to use `conda install jupyter` on Ubuntu 15.04, but it could not connect to the repositories of continuum, anyone knows what might be the problem?

```
:~$ conda install jupyter
Fetching package metadata: Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
....
Error: No packages found in current linux-64 channels matching: jupyter

You can search for this package on Binstar with

    binstar search -t conda jupyter
:~$ binstar search -t conda jupyter
Run 'binstar show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
Packages:
                          Name | Access       | Package Types   | Summary             
     ------------------------- | ------------ | --------------- | --------------------
          Rafayel/jupyterdrive | public       | conda           | Integration of IPython/Jupyter with Google drive
          anaconda-old/jupyter | public       | conda           | <Undefined>         
     anaconda-old/jupyter_console | public       | conda           | <Undefined>         
     anaconda-old/jupyter_core | public       | conda           | <Undefined>         
          minrk/jupyter_client | public       | conda           | Jupyter protocol implementation and client libraries
         minrk/jupyter_console | public       | conda           | Jupyter terminal console
            minrk/jupyter_core | public       | conda           | Jupyter core package. A base package on which Jupyter projects rely.
             qinves/jupyterhub | public       | conda           | JupyterHub: A multi-user server for Jupyter notebooks
        ukoethe/jupyter_client | public       | conda           | upyter protocol implementation and client libraries
          ukoethe/jupyter_core | public       | conda           | Jupyter core package
Found 10 packages
```

Comment: You don't seem to be able to connect to the default repos.

Can you open say this in your browser? https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/

Comment: Yes it opened in my browser

Comment: Can you install anything from the public channels using conda? The `Could not connect to...` errors suggest you can't reach the channel at all.

Comment: When I use `conda update --prefix /home/om/anaconda anaconda` it gives me again the same problem with the specific repositories, but then continues with the update procedure: `....
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment /home/om/anaconda:`

Comment: Even if conda cannot access remote channels (or the internet at all), it will happily continue, for example, to check any local default channels. So you need to figure out why conda cannot access the remote repos. It could for example be firewall or proxy issues.